# Find the arrival time of the first among N Brownian particles

Tags: probability, self-study, brownian-motion, levy-distribution

Based on the [first-hitting-time concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-hitting-time_model), the random propagation time $Z$ taken by a Brownian particle to reach the destination at a distance $d$ follows the [Levy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_distribution#Applications); and $\mathbb{E}[Z] = Var[Z]=\infty $. Then, if $N$ particles are released at time $t$ into a fluidic medium with no directional flow, we can write the arrival time vector, $\mathbf{Y}$,  as
\begin{equation} \label{eq_firstArrivalTime}
        \begin{aligned}
            \mathbf{Y} = t+\mathbf{Z},\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ (1)               
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
where $Z\sim \mathscr{L}(\mu,c)$ is a Levy distributed random variable with location parameter $\mu$ and scale parameter $c$.

I need to find the **random arrival time of the first particle** out of the $N$ Brownian particles that were released.
To my understanding, that time can be expressed as
\begin{equation} \label{eq_ShortedRandomTime}
        \begin{aligned}
           X = \text{min}\ \{\mathbf{Y}\},\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2) 
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
where $\mathbf{Y}$ is a random vector of $[Y_1,Y_2,\dots,Y_N]$ from (1). And if, $M$ MonteCarlo repetitions are performed, then we can have the random vector $\mathbf{X}$ = $[X_1,X_2,\dots,X_M]$.

**So, my question is, is (2) correct?**

Also, this might be a very weak inference but as $X$ is conditioned on the first particle arrival at the destination, $X$ is random but not Levy distributed right (but probably Normal distributed)?

**How do I go about to find that $X$ is random but not Levy distributed?**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I thought it was Weibull...

Comment: @HEITZ Sorry, but could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: sorry, I meant Wald http://www.math.chalmers.se/Stat/Grundutb/GU/MSF500/S15/LectureNotesExpanded.pdf

Comment: @HEITZ if there flow in the medium, then the first arrival time $Z$ is Wald/Inverse Gaussian, else it is Levy.

Comment: Glad to know I was right even if I get my ‘W’ distributions confused.

Comment: @HEITZ I am considering the case with no flow.